# How can I set up my Korg PadKontrol with Rock Band 3 Pro Drums mode?

Tags: rock-band-3

I have Rock Band 3 for PS3, the Mad Catz Midi adapter and a [Korg PadKontrol](http://www.korg.de/produkte/pc-tools/padkontrol-produktinfo/padkontrol-produktinfo-1.html) drum pad. Now I'd like to use all this in pro drums mode.

The PadKontrol is freely programmable, so it should work somehow, but I don't know the proper mappings. The manual lists the "midi numbers" I should program, so I tried programming the low tom (midi number 47, midi note B2), but it did not work. I have tried all 16 midi channels, but to no avail.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if these values do anything for you (from sethmeisterg):

```
MIDI Note Number / Rock Band 2 Equivalent
38, 40 / Red Pad
48, 50 / Yellow Pad
22, 26, 42, 44, 46 / Yellow Cymbal (hihat)
45 / Blue Pad
25, 51, 53, 59 / Blue Cymbal (ride)
41, 43 / Green Pad
49, 52, 55, 57 / Green Cymbal (crash)
36 / Kick Pedal
```